# mysql query taking long time to respond

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.department
     , t.owner
     , t.client
     , u.username as owner_name
     , c.name as catagery
     , d.dept_name as deptname
     , t.periority
     , t.status
     , t.estimate
     , cl.takeaway_name 
  from tbl_task t 
  JOIN tbl_user u 
    ON u.id = t.owner
  JOIN tbl_task_catagery c 
    ON c.id = t.catagery
  JOIN tbl_department d 
    ON d.id = t.department
  JOIN tbl_clients cl 
    ON cl.id = t.client 
   and t.status = 0 
   and (t.id in (select task_id 
                   from tbl_task_note tn 
                  where tn.user_id = '69' 
                    and tn.id in (select max(id) 
                                    from tbl_task_note tt 
                                   where tt.task_id = tn.task_id 
                                 )
                 )
        ) 
  order by t.id
```

Note : The above query is used for check users hold tasks. **tbl_task_note** table is used for check task notes for separate users task.

Comment: Did you put indexes on all your foreign keys ?

Comment: I presume your "question" is "how to make it less slow"? If so, then we need more info, such as do you have indexes and where? Is this ran in PHP, of so is it in a loop? Is the network fast? Could the data be cached perhaps?

Comment: No, i didn't add indexes.

Comment: The uncorellated subquery. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: As others have pointed out, at some point you're going to have to share with us SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Any indication of how many rows in your tables?

Answer (score 0):

With this query you will get the task that have the last task_note registered, including the user, departament, client, and some other.
   If it is what you need you can just do this.

```
select 
      t.id,
      t.department,
      t.owner,
      t.client,
      u.username as owner_name,
      c.name as catagery,
      d.dept_name as ptname,
      t.periority,
      t.status,
      t.estimate,
      cl.takeaway_name
      from tbl_task t
      INNER JOIN tbl_user u ON u.id=t.owner
      INNER JOIN tbl_task_catagery c ON c.id=t.catagery
      INNER JOIN tbl_department d ON d.id=t.department
      INNER JOIN tbl_clients cl ON cl.id=t.client and t.status=0 
      INNER JOIN (select * from tbl_task_note where id = 
                       (select max(id) from tbl_task_note)
                 )tb on tb.task_id = t.id
     order by t.id
```

That way you can improve your query.
  You shoud also ensure that your keys compared are foreign keys to get faster consults.

Comment: You can use the u.id in the select clause